# Movesense customgatt example not working?

Tags: gatt, movesense

I've built the `custom_gattsvc_app` and updated it into my movesense sensor through DFU in AndroidSampleApp. Now I am not anymore able to connect to the sensor. The sensor can be found by AndroidSampleApp as well as NRF Connect, but connecting does not work.

The sensor itself blinks in short intervals, perhaps it is in reset loop? I don't have a programming jig, so I can't even update it anymore (Cannot connect -> cannot update). I am using version 1.9.1. I've tested other example apps, such as `hello_world_app` and `ble_std_services`, and they have worked just fine.

Is there a known problem here?

Building done with following commands:

```
cmake -G Ninja -DMOVESENSE_CORE_LIBRARY=../MovesenseCoreLib/ -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../MovesenseCoreLib/toolchain/gcc-nrf52.cmake ../samples/custom_gattsvc_app
```

ninja dfupkg

Comment: I have tried the example now as well and can see the same problem. I also tried to connect with an nRF51 dongle and nRF connect from Nordic Semiconductor. The result of this is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The device might be crashing and trying to restart continuously. If you are not blinking the led and have turned off the BLE advertising in your code.

You should be able to recover by taking out the battery, short the two contacts with your finger(dip your finger in water if you have dry skin) and insert the battery, release the contacts immediately when the led starts to flash.

Your sensor should no be in DFU mode(led constantly on) and ready to update firmware. You can use the "nRF Toolbox" app(from the producer of the Bluetooth chip used in the Movesense device) to upload a new build of your code/example.

Comment: Thank you Morten. I think that the device is crashing and trying to restart continuously.  I managed to find the recovery information that you also told me and the device is now up and running (with different sw, not the custom gatt).


Still I would need to be able to create a custom gatt service. The example does not still work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Custom GATT Example seems to be working with version 1.8.1, so I will continue using that. Perhaps the problem is related to this: https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-device-lib/issues/70/version-190-and-191-and-send_ble_nus_data